# Trying to install Wolfram Mathematica on Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I recently upgraded from wheezy to jessie. During the installation Mathematica was removed. Trying to reinstall it via **sudo apt-get install wolfram-engine** produces the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wolfram-engine : Depends: libharfbuzz0a (>= 0.9.19-1co2rpi2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I have tried to install libharfbuzz0a (from both jessie and wheezy) but also get an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 librsvg2-2 : Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.36.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I stop going down this rabbit hole and get Mathematica working again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have asked [the same question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88917/mathematica-for-raspbian-8-aka-jessie) on mathematica.stackexchange.com and user [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) posted a very useful answer. Basically it is possible to install the latest Wolfram deb package `wolfram-engine_10.0.2+2015020304_armhf.deb` with `dpkg` and then fix an entry in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. Please refer to the exact details to ilian's post.

Credits are due to him alone, upvote his answer there! :-)

Comment: I tried that solution, but when I do `sudo apt-get -f install` I get this error: "The package wolfram-engine needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: Never mind, I got it now, the dpkg process got interrupted...

Comment: Now that the "official" Raspbian based on Jessie is out, I can confirm that it comes with Mathematica. Still Version 10.0.0 as with Wheezy.

Answer (score 1):

In the short term I'm not sure you can.

jessie is the current experimental build and you must expect broken packages every now and then.

You could approach the Raspbian maintainers and ask them when a fix is expected.  The answer may be "it'll be fixed when it's fixed".

Debian runs with three package distributions.

- stable: current code name wheezy
- experimental: current code name jessie
- testing: always called sid

Stick to stable if you want stability.

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the wolfram problem, Jessie is actually now the stable release of Debian: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/, but Raspbian has not caught up; perhaps the next release will and things like this will be fixed.

Comment: @goldilocks Oops, yes, I should have remembered that jessie had been promoted.

Comment: I'd be curious to find out to what extent the Foundation supports Raspbian.  If $0.50 from every pi sold had gone to them, I think they'd have plenty of resources to deal with this stuff and keep everything current.  But I suspect this is not the case (["financial costs related to development been funded out of pocket by project leader Mike Thompson"](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianDonate) --ouch).